# Objective Zip Password & CRC

Tags: ios, zip, objectivezip

I'm using Objective Zip to zip-up some files on my iOS app.

I want to protect them with a password and note the call...

```
- (ZipWriteStream *) writeFileInZipWithName:(NSString *)fileNameInZip fileDate:(NSDate *)fileDate compressionLevel:(ZipCompressionLevel)compressionLevel password:(NSString *)password crc32:(NSUInteger)crc32;
```

...requires a CRC32 value.

Not being expert on this, and having read-up about CRC on wikipedia etc., I'm still not sure what value to enter here.

Can it be zero?
Should it be the byte-count of the file? 
Any random number?

Help and guidance appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find the answer to this question?

Comment: Sadly, no. Do you have an answer?

Comment: No, trying to figure it out. Thanks for answering so quickly.

Comment: Any enlightenment would be appreciated if you do get anywhere. There must be someone out there who can help!!!

Comment: I ended up using ZipArchive. I do find that it is lacking, but that Objective-Zip is also lacking especially as pertains to catching NSException and using ARC. Ultimately I plan on transitioning away from using zip files, but for now, ZipArchive is what I will use in the short term. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: I made a fork of Objective-Zip named UnzipKit, which might help you out - it's easier to use, and you don't need to provide CRCs unless you want to. https://github.com/abbeycode/UnzipKit

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to calculate the CRC value for your file you want to zip:

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/path/to/your/file/to/zip"];
unsigned long result = crc32(0, data.bytes, (unsigned int)data.length);
```

Create a new Zip, add your file and pass the CRC result:

```
ZipFile *zipFile= [[ZipFile alloc] initWithFileName:@"/tmp/File.zip" mode:ZipFileModeCreate];
ZipWriteStream *stream= [zipFile writeFileInZipWithName:@"File.name" fileDate:[NSDate date] compressionLevel:ZipCompressionLevelDefault password:@"your_password"] crc32:result];
[stream writeData:data];
[stream finishedWriting];

[zipFile close];
```

Be sure that you the following line in zip.c (MiniZip) is uncommented:

```
//#define NOCRYPT
```

Also check that you have added the file **crypt.h** to your project.

Comment: Following these instructions did not solve the problem. I can't unzip the resulting zip file with wrong password error. Any ideas? Please note that I am zipping more files in the same archive.

Comment: Does it work if you zip only one file? Which software do you use for unzipping?

Comment: I will try with a single file. For unzipping I use "The Unarchiver" for Mac. But I also tried shell utilities on linux and mac...